# How to pass a parameter and get the event caller JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, laravel-blade

I need to pass parameter from HTML to the JS function. I can't set unique id, because elements are in loop. So it looks like this:

```
   @foreach ($meals as $meal)
       <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addToCart('{{ $meal->id }}')">
   @endforeach
```

But in calling function, I need access both to input parameter and event caller:

```
        let addToCart = (id, caller) => {
            console.log(id);
            console.log(caller);
        }
```

I tried to put `this` as second parameter, when calling function:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addToCart('{{ $meal->id }}', this)">
```

Well, it works, but my next task is to replace event caller with some other DOM element, using JQuery.

```
        let addToCart = (id, caller) => {
            caller.replaceWith("<h1>helloworld</h1>");
        }
```

Unfortunately that replaces event caller with that, only as innerHTML of parent element, without interacting with tags. So, I'm getting smthing like this:

[image]

What can I do in that case?

UPD:
I'm getting this:
[image]

But I need THIS:
[image]

Comment: to answer the question in your title it was as easy as doing`window.event.target` or `window.event.currentTarget` (this second option is safer in case the event will bubble to the parent). You solved anyway passing `this` when invoking the handler. But the final issue is unclear. Your handler literally replaces the event target (the button firing the click event) with a custom html and it behaves as expected.

Comment: _"Unfortunately that replaces event caller with that, only as innerHTML of parent element, without interacting with tags. So, I'm getting smthing like this"_ ... this part is very confusing. What did you mean to do instead? how did you expect your event target to change?

Comment: @DiegoD Thanks for your answer. Updated the question, hope it makes clearer, what I need to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you meant to replace the button that fired the click event with a different html object instead of just replacing its text content like you did in your example, the key was using `replaceWith` on a jQuery object instead of calling it from an HTMLDocument.

The difference between https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/replaceWith and https://api.jquery.com/replacewith/

So to force the invocation from the jQuery object, just use `$(caller)`

```js
let addToCart = (id, caller) => {
    $(caller).replaceWith( "<h1>helloworld</h1>" );      
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addToCart('id', this)">click to replace</button>
```